# Change the meaning of \d for one character

Tags: macros, hyperref

I'd like to change the meaning of `\d{}` from under-dot to over-dot just for the characters `c` and `C`. That is, `\d{c}` and `\d{C}` will mean `\.c` and `\.C`, respectively, but `\d{}` will retain its original meaning for all other characters.

I could use `\renewcommand{\d}{...}` to do that, but I realize redefining \d{} is risky. Worse, I am using the "hyperref" package, which redefines `\d{}` internally. Even if I do redefine `\d{}`, hyperref overrides my redefinition, since it is loaded last.

I could go through my files and change the `\d{c}` to `\.c` everywhere with a global replace in vim, but there are many files, and hundreds of replacements in each file. I risk introducing errors.

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm using XeLaTeX with package fontspec. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just put your `\renewcommand{\d}{...}` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I would change all `\d{` in your document with `\ad{` (for example, meaning "autodot", but whatever new available command will do) and then use one of the answer here to *define* `\ad` (and not redefine `\d{`.) Maybe it seems overkill now, but it will pay in the future... for example when you share your document with somebody who wants `\d{c}` to work as ever (maybe even yourself in another document).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the existing composite accent machinery to redefine the composite for T1 (or whichever encoding you are using)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{T1}{c}{\.c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{T1}{C}{\.C}
\begin{document}

\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}
\end{document}
```

or with PU encoding for bookmarks

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{T1}{c}{\.c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{T1}{C}{\.C}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{c}{\.c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{C}{\.C}
\begin{document}

\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}

\section{section{\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}}}

\end{document}
```

with xetex of course you would use TU rather than T1 encoding so

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{TU}{c}{\.c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{TU}{C}{\.C}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{c}{\.c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{C}{\.C}
\begin{document}

\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}

\section{section{\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP is using XeLaTeX…

Comment: @egreg added TU ..

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether this is really a good idea, and I'd certainly advocate for fixing the input (you could do that programmatically once and match only `\d{c}` and `\d{C}`).

However, the following copies the definition of `\d` and then redefines it to check whether the input argument is `c` or `C`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \NewCommandCopy \ajya_orig_d:n \d
    \RenewDocumentCommand \d { m }
      {
        \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
          { \str_if_eq_p:nn {#1} { c } }
          { \str_if_eq_p:nn {#1} { C } }
          { \. {#1} }
          { \ajya_orig_d:n {#1} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\d{a}\d{c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\str_case:nnF { #1 } { {c}{\.{#1}}{C}{\.{#1}} } { \ajya_orig_d:n {#1} }`

Comment: @egreg Would work as well, yes. Does it have any advantage which I don't see atm?

Comment: I believe it's simpler (and extensible).

Comment: @egreg but my version's simpler still:-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd do this, but you may have some reasons to.

You want to ensure that also the bookmarks are treated the same way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ajya_d_old:n \d
\cs_new:Nn \ajya_d_new:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {c}{\.{#1}}
    {C}{\.{#1}}
    % maybe some other cases
   }
   {
    \ajya_d_old:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\d}{m}{\ajya_d_new:n {#1}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \d \ajya_d_new:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}

\section{\d{c}\d{C}\d{u}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\DeclareUnicodeComposite{\d}{c}{"010B}
\DeclareUnicodeComposite{\d}{C}{"010A}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{c}{\81\013}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{C}{\81\012}` ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's a good idea! If the mysterious `\81\013` were well-documented…

Comment: @UlrikeFischer knows the internal PDF codes but normal people can use `\.i`:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know them, I only know where to look them up ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Das gleiche gilt für jede Sprache

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the series of wonderful solutions!The main reason for me to change from c/C under-dot to c/C over-dot is that unicode provides a glyph for the latter, bot not for the former. This simplifies conversions from PDF to text/Word, for example, since kerning-based solutions don't always convert well. I was using EB Garamond, which has a great look. It produced excellent output with pdfLaTeX, but had serious conversion issues with diacritics. I moved to XeLaTeX, and used a font with enough glyphs and diacritics.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this correctly, you can create explicit overdot commands for particular characters, check for the existence of such a function for a given character, and call it if it exists. Else, if no such function exists, you need to maintain the original command \d{} for all non-'C' scenarios:

```
%copy \d so standard functionality isn't lost
\global\let\oldD\d

%create new function for overdot 'C'
\global\newcommand{\dC}{%
    \.{C}\ignorespaces
}

%create new function for overdot 'c'
\global\newcommand{\dc}{%
    \.{c}\ignorespaces
}

%redefine \d to do \oldD unless an explicit command exists
%in this case, \dC
\global\renewcommand{\d}[1]{%
    \ifcsname d#1\endcsname
        \csname d#1\endcsname\ignorespaces
    \else
        \oldD{#1}\ignorespaces
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\d{F}|\d{c}|\d{C}|\d{u}

\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]

The approach above allows you to outline other specific character functions as necessary while maintaining the original function (as redefined by hyperref) as the default.

I checked this with the redefine's in the preamble and using hyperref package, and it was successful.